# Pushing one git branch requires a pull on another?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'm a bit of a git n00b, and I am having some difficulty with branches. I don't think this question has been asked, however it could just be that I'm not looking for the right keywords.

Situation:
I have a remote git repository and I have checked out the master branch on machine 1.
I have done the same on machine 2, except that I have created a new branch (sandbox) and checked that out.

I pull, make changes, commit and push stuff on Machine 2 - no problems.

I then make some changes on Machine one, commit, and try to push, except I get this error:

```
To xxx@xxx.xxx.com:/project.git
! [rejected]        sandbox -> sandbox (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'xxx@xxx.xxx.com:/project.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

If I do a git pull, I get:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

So at the moment I have to

```
git checkout sandbox
git pull
git checkout master
git push
```

And then its all fine. It seems to me, that given these are different branches, there should be no need for me to do a pull on the sandbox branch to push changes on master. I could understand it if I was trying to merge them back, but that will probably never happen.

I suspect my config file is a bit wrong, so here it is:

```
(Machine 1 - master) .git/config

[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 1920x970+0+0 368 203

[remote "origin"]
    url = xxx@xxx.xxx.com:/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

And

```
(Machine 2 - paid) .git/config

[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true

[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git+ssh://xxx@xxx.xxx.com/project.git

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

[branch "sandbox"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/sandbox
```

It should be noted, the the same problem happens in revers - after a push on master, I can't to a push on sandbox without checking out master, doing a pull and then switching back to sandbox.

There must be an easier way - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer:

```
git config --global push.default tracking
```

This seems to have solved by problem.

Aquired answer courtesy of [This Site](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/)